# Laravel 5.5 install not generating .env file

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.5

I have installed laravel 5.4 multiple times.
Now I'm trying to install laravel 5.5 using same command And it doesn't work.

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog dev-develop
```

It doesn't seem to have any errors on installation, only lot of suggestions.
But no key is generated and no .env file is created.
When I try to make php artisan key:generate

```
/public_html/blog/.env): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: could you tell us your OS? its a bit weird if the `.env` file is not created.. even in Windows it is created correctly.. although you cant make another file with that name in Windows Explorer.. and make sure to check your directory whether the file is exists or not.

Answer (score 5):

Got the same problem days a go, the problem was because composer was not updated, solved it updating composer, you can run:

```
composer self-update
```

Or you can download the latest version [there](https://getcomposer.org/download/), then you can create the project again and the `.env` file will be automatically created.

Comment: I cant run composer self-update. I get an error comand not defines

Comment: @Kezern you have a lot of guides how to update composer, just update it and then creating a laravel project will work as expected.

Comment: @Kezern you probably can't run it because you installed it using apt-get or a similar service. Install it following the official guideline on [composer's official website](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx) and you'll be just fine!

Answer (score 1):

I have this version

```
Composer version @package_branch_alias_version@ (1.0.0-beta2) 2016-03-27 16:00:34
```

When I run composer self-update I get

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]
 Command "self-update" is not defined.
```

Answer (score 0):

shell command: `cp .env.example .env`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make current setup work, just try doing the following:

cp .env.example .env
php artisan key:generate

But as suggested by one of the answers here, you should update your composer if you have an old version. To check your installed version, do so with composer -v

Comment: Try installing composer again. Current version listed online is as follows:
1.5.1 (2017-08-09)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of your **Laravel Installer** or **Composer** version. I have faced the same problem and found following *2 different solutions*:

1. Generally, you can solve with by running `composer global update` command and then run `composer update` command from your project directory. This solution basically updates your installer and then your project.
2. If still, you have this problem, then you need to run `composer self-update` command first and then run `composer update` command from your project directory. It will update your composer version and then your project.

Hope this information will help you to fix.